# Java regex - one liner for counting matches

Tags: java, regex

Is there a one liner to replace the while loop?

```
String formatSpecifier = "%(\\d+\\$)?([-#+ 0,(\\<]*)?(\\d+)?(\\.\\d+)?([tT])?([a-zA-Z%])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(formatSpecifier);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("hello %s my name is %s");

// CAN BELOW BE REPLACED WITH A ONE LINER?
int counter = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Umm, you are matching on the literal `String` "infile.txt" - it doesn't read from a file for you.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I updated the question with a better example.

Comment: Any reason for needing a one-liner, given the original code is just 3-4 lines which is short and easy to read?

Comment: Not in Java 8 if you need the same performance. But you may in Java 9. Why not write a separate method and call it as a one-liner?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I don't see any reason to aim for one-liner given the original code is already easy to understand.  Anyway, several ways if you insists:

### 1. Make a helper method

make something like this

```
static int countMatches(Matcher matcher) {
  int counter = 0;
  while (matcher.find())
    counter++;
  return counter;
}
```

so your code become

```
int counter = countMatches(matcher);
```

### 2. Java 9

`Matcher` in Java 9 provides `results()` which returns a `Stream<MatchResult>`.  So your code becomes

```
int counter = matcher.results().count();
```

### 3. String Replace

Similar to what the other answer suggest.

Here I am replacing with null character (which is almost not used in any normal string), and do the counting by split:

Your code become:

```
int counter = matcher.replaceAll("\0").split("\0", -1).length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes: replace any occurrence by a char that can be neither in the pattern nor in the string to match, then count the number of occurrences of this char.
Here I choose X, for the example to be simple. You should use a char not so often used (see UTF-8 special chars for instance).

```
final int counter = pattern.matcher("hello %s my name is %s").replaceAll("X").replaceAll("[^X]", "").length();
```

Value computed for counter is 2 with your example.

Comment: You would need a _difference_ in length.  But even then, the bigger issue is that for a regex pattern like `(?*?)` we don't know the width of each replacement in advance.

Comment: Your regex pattern does not work when inserted in the original question (throws java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException). I do not see why a difference? Can you give an example that works with the code in the original question and for which my answer does not work, please ? (format specifier **and** string to match)

Comment: @Alexandre `"XXX"`.

Comment: As I've written in my answer, X is only for the example to be simple: *you should use a char not so often used* (this is why I talked about UTF-8 special chars). Of course, if you choose a char that is Inside the pattern or the string to match, it can not work correctly.